# In T-SQL what is the best design for multiple INNER JOINs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have looked for a similar issue to no avail. If I have missed the solution, my apologies and please point me in the right direction.

I have be playing with MS AdventureWorks and would like to know if there is any functional difference between two SELECT statements using INNER JOIN that I have created. They give the same results.

**Version 1**

```
SELECT  pp.BusinessEntityID, pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName, pp.Suffix, 
    pe.EmailAddress, 
    pa.AddressLine1, pa.AddressLine2, pa.City, pa.PostalCode FROM 
Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea 
INNER JOIN  Person.Address AS pa 
    ON bea.AddressID = pa.AddressID 
INNER JOIN  Person.Person AS pp 
    ON bea.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID   
INNER JOIN  Person.EmailAddress AS pe 
    ON pp.BusinessEntityID = pe.BusinessEntityID 
WHERE pp.Suffix IS NOT NULL
```

---

**Version 2**

```
SELECT      pp.BusinessEntityID, pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName, pp.Suffix,
        pe.EmailAddress,
        pa.AddressLine1, pa.AddressLine2, pa.City, pa.PostalCode 
FROM        Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea 
        INNER JOIN Person.Address AS pa 
            ON bea.AddressID = pa.AddressID 
        INNER JOIN Person.Person AS pp 
            ON bea.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID
        INNER JOIN Person.EmailAddress AS pe 
            ON bea.BusinessEntityID = pe.BusinessEntityID 
WHERE     pp.Suffix IS NOT NULL
```

The only difference is in the last ON clause. The design diagrams look quite different though
Any thoughts would be very welcome

Answer (score 3):

No difference here, because equality is transitive. (*)

However, if you had OUTER JOINS mixed in somewhere, the result may well be different.

(*) I'd take a look at the execution plan for both, though, because the query planner may not be clever enough to choose the best option and by phrasing it differently, may be coerced one way or the other. You could also try throwing in the redundant third equality. While they all arrive at the same result, the order of how joins are performed can lead to drastically different execution times.